# Prism: The Button become disable After implement DataErrorValidationRule to TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

maybe i missed something, but i implemented `IDataErrorInfo` to TextBox to return error message when user enter null or empty and used`SubmitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();` in the setter of TextBox Property to notify Button Enable or Disable.
i have dialog to show three textBoxs one of theme Title TextBox, so i implement `CanSubmit` for Button to return `true` or `false` according to `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title)`, so here what i did in `AddBookDialogViewModel.cs`:

```
public class AddBookDialogViewModel : BindableBase
 {
     public DelegateCommand SubmitCommand { get; set; }

     private string title;
     public string Title
     {
         get { return title; }
         set
         {
             SetProperty(ref title, value);
             SubmitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
         }
     }
// .. other properties

    public AddBookDialogViewModel()
    {
       SubmitCommand = new DelegateCommand(Submit, CanSubmit);
    }
    private bool CanSubmit()
    {
       Console.WriteLine($"Button Is {!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title)}");
       return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title);
    }

    private void Submit()
    {
        DialogHost.Close("RootDialog", GetParas());
    }

    private object GetParas()
    {
        return new
        {
           Title,
           Auther,
           Date
        };
    }
```

and this the `AddBookDialogView.xaml`:

```
<TextBox
    md:HintAssist.Hint="أسم الكتاب"
    Focusable="True"
    MaxLength="30"
    Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Style="{StaticResource TxtBox}"/>
<!--other TextBoxs-->
<Button
    Width="150"
    Margin="0,5,5,0"
    Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
    Content="أضافة"
    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatLightBgButton}" />
```

so everything now work fine the Button Disable and Enable according to `return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title);`.
The outbut:

```
Button Is False
Button Is True
Button Is False
Button Is True
```

The problem coming up when i implement `IDataErrorInfo`:

```
    public class AddBookDialogViewModel : BindableBase, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        public DelegateCommand SubmitCommand { get; set; }

        private string title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return title; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref title, value);
                SubmitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
        
      
        public AddBookDialogViewModel()
        {
            SubmitCommand = new DelegateCommand(Submit, CanSubmit);
        }

        private bool CanSubmit()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Button Is {!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title)}");
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title);
        }

        #region DataValidation
        
        public string Error
        {
            get
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                string result = null;
                if (columnName == "Title")
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title?.ToString()))
                    {
                        result = "Required";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = null;
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
        #endregion DataValidation
        private void Submit()
        {
            DialogHost.Close("RootDialog", GetParas());
        }

        private object GetParas()
        {
            return new
            {
                Title,
                Auther,
                Date
            };
        }
    }
```

and i edit The TextBox Of Title in `AddBookDialogView.xaml` like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <src1:AddBookDialogViewModel x:Key="data" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<TextBox
    md:HintAssist.Hint="أسم الكتاب"
    Focusable="True"
    MaxLength="30"
    Style="{StaticResource TxtBox}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding
            Path="Title"
            Source="{StaticResource data}"
            UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
            ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <DataErrorValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>

<!---Submit Button--->
<Button
    Width="150"
    Margin="0,5,5,0"
    Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
    Content="أضافة"
    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatLightBgButton}" />
```

Now Submit Button still Disable after The title property changed and output print just one line:

```
Button Is False
```

I'm using Prism.Unity 8.1.97 with MaterialDesignThemes 4.9.0.

Edit:
I used another approach by using [Prism.Validation](https://github.com/mfe-/Prism.Validation) now everything works perfectly.

my `AddBookDialogViewModel.cs` look like this:

```
public class AddBookDialogViewModel : ValidatableBindableBase
{
    public DelegateCommand SubmitCommand { get; set; }
    private string title;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "هذا الحقل مطلوب")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "اسم كامل")]
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref title, value);
        }
    }
// other properties
   public AddBookDialogViewModel()
   {
    SubmitCommand = new DelegateCommand(Submit, CanSubmit).
        ObservesProperty(() => Title).
        ObservesProperty(() => Auther).
        ObservesProperty(() => Date);
   }

   private bool CanSubmit()
   {
    return !HasErrors;
   }

   private void Submit()
   {
    DialogHost.Close("RootDialog", GetParas());
   }

   private object GetParas()
   {
    return new
    {
        Title,
        Auther,
        Date
    };
   }
}
```

and `AddBookDialogView.xaml`

```
<TextBox
  x:Name="Title"
  md:HintAssist.Hint="أسم الكتاب"
  Focusable="True"
  MaxLength="30"
  Style="{StaticResource TxtBox}"
  Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay, 
  ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<Button
  Width="150"
  Margin="0,5,5,0"
  Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
  Content="أضافة"
  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatLightBgButton}" />
```